# How pass this value to setinterval on onload function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to send this to a function called using setInterval on image's onload event but it throws the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'attr' of undefined(…)

```
<img src="image.jpg" id="24" onload="var sel =this;setInterval(function(sel){calllogin(sel)},20000);"
<script>
function calllogin(sel){
  var id = sel.attr("id");
  console.log('calling calllogin function',id);
}
</script>
```

How can I pass this?

Comment: Remove `sel` from `setInterval` function callback argument i.e.  `setInterval(function(){calllogin(sel)},20000)`

Comment: In addition, you're missing a `}` to close your function `calllogin`

Comment: @Satpal I removed it, now it shows the following error ; Uncaught TypeError: sel.attr is not a function(…)

Comment: `$(sel).attr("id");` Read @Rajaprabhu answer

Comment: @Satpal thank you bro it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to remove `setInterval(function(sel)`, `sel` from the function parameter.

```
onload="var sel =this; setInterval(function(){ calllogin(sel) },20000);"
```

Or just pass the `sel` as a third parameter to setInterval

```
setInterval(function(sel){calllogin(sel)},20000, sel);
```

and the `sel` inside callBack will not be a jquery object. It will be a simple element object. You have to convert it before consuming a Jquery's function.

```
function calllogin(sel) {
  var id = $(sel).attr("id");
  console.log('calling calllogin function',id);
}
```

Comment: @scriptkiddie1, Consider accepting the answer. See [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)